# why matlab gpu computing seems lower than cpu?

Tags: matlab, gpu

as I run the codes below, the time consumption was about:`t1 =3.0205,t2 =11.2895`.
t1 was the computation time on cpu, while t2 was the computation time on gpu.why it consume much more time on gpu in this case???

```
    clear all
    clc
    M = rand(2000,2000);            % 生成一个随机矩阵
    tic
    [A1,B1] = eig(M);                    % 求该随机矩阵的特征值和特征向量
    t1=toc
    tic
    M = single(M);                     % 将数据转换为单精度型
    M = gpuArray(M);                % 将数据从CPU中搬到GPU
    [A2,B2] = eig(M);                 % 求特征值和特征向量
    A2 = gather(A2);                 % 将数据从GPU中搬到CPU
    t2 = toc
```

the calculation was based on matlab 2021b(default :cuda 11.0), my GPU device is GeForce RTX 3090 with cuda version 11.6

```
  CUDADevice - 属性:

                  Name: 'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090'
                 Index: 1
     ComputeCapability: '8.6'
        SupportsDouble: 1
         DriverVersion: 11.6000
        ToolkitVersion: 11
    MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
      MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
    MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
           MaxGridSize: [2.1475e+09 65535 65535]
             SIMDWidth: 32
           TotalMemory: 2.5769e+10
       AvailableMemory: 2.3882e+10
   MultiprocessorCount: 82
          ClockRateKHz: 1695000
           ComputeMode: 'Default'
  GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
      CanMapHostMemory: 1
       DeviceSupported: 1
       DeviceAvailable: 1
        DeviceSelected: 1
```

Comment: `clear all` removes all loaded code from memory, not only variables. This makes subsequent function calls much slower. You should not use it. Do `clear` by itself instead, it will clear the workspace but leave everything intact. -- Regarding your question: it looks like eigenvalue decomposition is not something that can be efficiently implemented on the GPU.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! Could you please provide some typical test code to verify if my gpu is working properly?

Comment: Try GPUBench https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34080-gpubench - this has a number of different benchmark calculations

Comment: your answer really helps a lot, a I still wonder why it cost much more time if I use GPU.